# Resultados diferentes do mesmo aplicativo com SQLite

Tags: sqlite

As telas anexas são o resultado da mesma consulta num tablet com Android 4.1.2 e num Galaxy S3 com Android 4.3 (a que tem o Brasil apenas uma vez, o que é correto) e outra com o Moto X2 com Android 6.0 (com os dados do Brasil divididos) no mesmo aplicativo que está na Play Store no link abaixo.

Executando o SQL num banco de dados Firebird também fica correto.

O SQL usado é o seguinte:

```
select ‘’ as est_estado,
(case when d.tor_intern = ‘S’ then est_pais else
b.clu_estado end) as est_pais,
count(*) as pon_titulo
from PONTOS a, CLUBES b, ESTADOS c, TORNEIOS d
where a.tor_codigo = ‘CONMEB’ AND
a.clu_ordem = b.clu_ordem and
b.clu_estado = c.clu_estado and
a.tor_codigo = d.tor_codigo AND
pon_classi = 1
group by est_estado, est_pais
order by pon_titulo desc, est_pais
```

[image: Tela certa]

[image: Tela errada]

[Para baixar o app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.danieltiburciosf.rankingfutebol)